# How to space data points horizontally in D3?

Tags: arrays, d3.js

I have an array of data and I wish to present it as a bunch of dots. The values from the array are y-coordinates and they work. However, I'm unclear on how to space out the elements horizontally. The spacing is equidistant, if it's of any relevance.

```
graph1.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(huh) { return 10; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d; })
  .attr("r", "5")
  .attr("class", "dataPoint");
```

How can I express *huh* and *10*? The only approach I can think is to declare an auxiliary array. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the index (second argument passed to the function):

```
.attr("cx", function(d, i) { return i * totalWidth / (data.length - 1); })
```